# How to draw chart with named range reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

In Excel I have a range **C14:D19** named as **income_range** which contains some data of category in one column and amount in other column, so to make it dynamic I have created a named range of it(Income_range).
so I'm trying to create a donut chart out of this **income_range** data, but I'm not getting an exact way on how to achieve this. how to achieve this.